# Differentt style if it's OS / iphone

Tags: javascript, ios, dom, tags

I have a problem  in rendering my fonts in iphone, or ipad, this is my proposal by JS, does'nt work ?

```
var iOS = /iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.userAgent) && !window.MSStream;
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("h1");
var i;


if (iOS) {
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  x[i].style.letterSpacing = "0px!important";
}
}
else {  
   for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  x[i].style.letterSpacing = "2px!important";
}  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is because you need a space in between the sizing and the '!important' attribute.

This:

```
x[i].style.letterSpacing = "2px!important"
```

becomes

```
x[i].style.letterSpacing = "2px !important"
```

On another point, I'd recommend declaring 'i' in the for loop, unless you specifically need it later on. Also, I'd recommend keeping your code tidy, even in development, and especially when asking others for help, as you have a couple indentation problems.